# Xpath in Query to search all child nodes

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, xpath

I'm using postgres. My data is in xml format. I want to write a query to obtain the matching record. The record might be in any of child element. I need to use the result of XPath in the query.

Sample data:

```
<book category="Cooking">
          <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
          <author>Leonard Richardson</author>
          <author>Sam Ruby</author>
          <year>2007</year>
          <price>58.33</price>
</book>
```

Query 1:

```
SELECT id, xmldata
FROM tblprofile AS a
WHERE 'Sam Ruby' = CAST((xpath('/book/author/text()', xmldata))[1] AS TEXT)
```

This did not fetch any result.

Query 2:

```
SELECT id, xmldata
FROM tblprofile AS a
WHERE 'Leonard Richardson' = CAST((xpath('/book/author/text()', xmldata))[1] AS TEXT)
```

fetches the result as the above query matches the first entry. How to make the query 1 working? How to search in all child nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only need to check if exists `author` element with certain value in the XML column in your where clause, then `XMLEXISTS()` would be more suitable:

```
SELECT id, xmldata FROM tblprofile AS a 
WHERE  XMLEXISTS('/book/author[.="Sam Ruby"]' PASSING a.xmldata)
```

**<kbd>[demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p3zDRMYtKRLHXRMfVmLLDN/0)</kbd>**